# SAPI 5 voice synthesis and C#

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, sapi

I have installed new SAPI5 voice. In computer settings of Speech program is new voice visible and available to use. But my program cannot find it. To find it, I am using this part of code, I use `System.Speech.Synthesis` namespace.

```
SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
foreach (InstalledVoice v in s.GetInstalledVoices())
{
    st += v.VoiceInfo.Name+"\n";
}

MessageBox.Show(st);
```

The only voice found is Microsoft Anna. My code for speeking is as follow:

```
s.SelectVoice("Eliska22k");//name of the voice is Eliska22k

s.Speak("ahoj");
```

I am using C# 4 and I have windows vista 32 bit. Where is my mistake? Is in the code or anywhere else?

**EDIT:**
requested registry values:

in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices*

DefaultTokenId: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\TokenEnums\Infovox Desktop v2.2\Eliska22k

DefaultTTSRate: 0

in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\TokenEnums\Infovox Desktop v2.2\Eliska22k*

405: Eliska (Czech) SAPI5

CLSID: {F8E89351-F6B9-4C98-91F9-A967BA752655}

VoiceData: Eliska22k

in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\TokenEnums\Infovox Desktop v2.2\Eliska22k\Attributes*

Age: Adult

AudioFormats 18

Gender: Female

Language: 405;5

Name: Eliska22k

Comment: Document the content of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices registry key.

Comment: Use SpeechSynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices() to make sure it finds the voice, and the name matches to the one you try to select.

Comment: I am already try this with GetInstalledVoices(), voice is not foud, @HansPassant what kind of information do you nedd?

Comment: @HansPassant I have added registry information

Comment: @Vodáček I'm interested in czech voice speech. Can I ask you there you found this voice and if is it working correctly with .NET speech? Thanks.

Comment: How can I install more voices, I only have Microsoft Anna.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the target platform and Framework version of your .NET project. Some voices are supported only for x86.