# Add another voice into .NET Speech

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, speech

How can I add another voice into .NET Speech? I'd like to use Czech voice. I've found some `*.sis` files `Eliska22k.sis` but I don't know how to use it.

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
foreach (var voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
    Console.WriteLine(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
```

Gives me only `Microsoft Anna`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, There aren't good news for you.
1. [Language Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476) - Czech language isn't supported by MS TTS.
2. `sis` is Symbian installer file and is useless in Windows.
3. Other languages can be found there: [Download Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime Languages (Version 11) from Official Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224) - They are just some `msi` files, so there are no tricks installing them.

Try to find another text-to-speech library, which supports czech language.

Comment: I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501411/sapi-5-voice-synthesis-and-c-sharp And as I understood he installed voice called Eliska22k which is czech voice.

Comment: @sczdavos, probably, he bought it [here](http://www.acapela-group.com/infovox3-37-3-speech-solutions-tts.html). I think, you should ask author of this question about it.